# Splitting array by comparing keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have an array like this;

```
Array
(
    [database1.table1.fieldname] => "test"
    [database1.table1.fieldname1] => "test1"
    [database2.table2.fieldname] => "test2"
)
```

Here for the first two values the `database name` and `table name` are the same. Fieldname is not so important here. For the third value the database name and table name are different. What I want to achieve is that I want to split this array in to seperate arrays by comparing the database name and table name. I need to achieve something like this;

```
Array
(
    [database1.table1.fieldname] => "test"
    [database1.table1.fieldname1] => "test1"
)

Array
(
    [database2.table2.fieldname] => "test2"
)
```

Is it possible to do something like this?.

Comment: what about database1.table2.fieldname. where will this go?

Comment: That also need to be in a seperate array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
foreach($my_arr as $key=>$value) {

    $new_key = explode('.',$key);
    if($new_key[0] == "datebase1" && $new_key[1] == "table1") {
         $arr1[$key] = $value;
    } elseif ($new_key[0] == "datebase2" && $new_key[1] == "table2") {
         $arr2[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Or you can try like

```
foreach($my_arr as $key=>$value) {

    $new_key = explode('.',$key);
    $new_arr[$new_key[0]][$new_key[1]][] = array($key=>$value);
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
  [database1] => Array
    (
        [table1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [database1.table1.fieldname] => test
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [database1.table1.fieldname1] => test1
                    )

            )
    )

  [database2] => Array
    (
        [table2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [database2.table2.fieldname] => test3
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But my problem is that the name 'database1' and all is coming dynamically. So it's not possible to just compare with the database and table names.

Comment: See my edited answer...from $new_arr you can get the desired output.You can the indiviual from that

Comment: From your answer if I need to get the value "[database1.table1.fieldname] => test" I need to use $new_arr['database1']['table1'][0]. But my problem is I can't use 'database1' and 'table1' here. Instead that also I need to do dynamically. Any solution for that?.

Comment: you can use foreach loop with the new_arr and check for the database and table names that comes dynamically

Comment: change this line $new_arr[$new_key[0]][$new_key[1]][] = array($key=>$value); with $new_arr[$new_key[0]][$new_key[1]][$key] =$value;

Comment: I resolved it myself. But thanks for the support. @Gautam3164 your solution made the way to solve the issue. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. Take it.

```
function splitDatabaseArray($array)
    {
    ksort($array);
    $return = array();
    $last_database_table = array();
    foreach ($array as $index => $value)
        {
        $database_table = array();
        list($database_table[0], $database_table[1]) = explode('.', $index);
        if ($last_database_table != $database_table)
            $row = &$return[];
        $last_database_table = $database_table;
        $row[$index] = $value;
        }
    return $return;
    }

$array = array
    (
    'database1.table1.fieldname' => "test",
    'database1.table1.fieldname1' => "test1",
    'database2.table2.fieldname' => "test2");

var_dump(splitDatabaseArray($array));
```

http://3v4l.org/TC542